# How to save a SimpleDocTemplate PDF to a specific directory

Tags: reportlab

I want to save a PDF created with SimpleDocTemplate to the same directory of an input file I used to create it. I get the directory info. correctly; add it to the name of the pdf to be created but it won't save it to that directory.

```
filename = askopenfilename(initialdir="c:/Documents/")
import os
dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(filename))
dir_name = dir_name + "/scoresheet.pdf"
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(dir_name, pagesize=letter)
doc.build(sheet)
```

I receive no error messages and the PDF gets created but not in the directory of the input document (from askopenfilename...). It's saved to the directory of where I initiated the Python code. I print off the dir_name and it shows the correct directory structure but it doesn't save the PDF there.

Comment: "the name of the pdf to be created" is exactly what you said, not the directory of the pdf to be created. If we analyse the source code of both `platyplus` and `canvas` we'll see that there is no parameter to set the diretory of the pdf, unfortunately.

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out you can use os.path.realpath to get the entire directory. Specifically: dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(filename)